# Entering fullscreen in mednafen with ONE monitor?

Tags: resolution, emulation

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS x86_64 with two mismatched monitors: one, a laptop @ 1366x768 native, the other an Asus @ 1920x1080 native res. How can I enter fullscreen with mednafen displaying on just one monitor, leaving the other one untouched? The problem with just hitting atl+enter after booting up a game normally is my large display shrinks and both monitors mirror (and stay mirrored afterward).

This is just a pain and passing arguments like -pcfx.xres 1366 -pcfx.yres 768 from a bash script just results in the game being displayed across both monitors.
If anyone has some tips that I could learn from, it'd be appreciated.

Edits: if it helps, compizconfig is set to detect my outputs (display settings).

Here is the output when running a game via bash script

```
Initializing sound...
 Using "ALSA" audio driver with SexyAL's default device selection.ALSA Error: snd_pcm_open(&alsa_pcm, id ? id : "hw:0", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0) Device or resource busy
Error opening a sound device.
Initializing video...
 Video Driver: OpenGL
 Video Mode: 3286 x 1080 x 32 bpp
  Pixel shader: none
 Fullscreen: Yes
 Special Scaler: None
 Scanlines: Off
 Destination Rectangle: X=922, Y=60, W=1440, H=960
 OpenGL Implementation: Tungsten Graphics, Inc Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile  2.1 Mesa 8.0.4
 Checking extensions:
  GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two found.
 Using non-power-of-2 sized textures.
 Checking maximum texture size...
  Apparently it is at least: 8192 x 8192
 Using GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV for texture source data.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set these environment variables as shown, in your bash script, before running `mednafen`, and it will full screen only on the primary display.

```
export SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_DISPLAY=0
export SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_HEAD=0
```

You may also need to update the configuration in `~/.mednafen/mednafen.cfg` to not have the very large resolution specifications set, had they been set to the large values previously.

Comment: Hmm, still results in mednafen spanning both monitors.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm still unable to work this. Like you suggested, I edited x and yres in mednafen.cfg.. no go.

Comment: Ok, I went ahead and fixed it myself. Turns out I had to set pce scaling options to their default values. Works great. Thanks. :)